# Open Window in all the machines that connected to my network using C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, windows-services

the question is i have to develop a simple solution where i have a database contain the name of restaurants in our city and it's items and we have a network more than 100 pc's connected to it what i want to do is any one can start an order and send to all the machines on the same network like a pop up window with the name of the restaurant like a flag that i am ordering from a restaurant and share in the order by setting number of meals and the name of it   and any one refresh the Oder will see the new items added to the order any help ,links or articles  will be good

Answer (score 1):

The first think I would say is that this sounds like a really bad idea. But that is not my call. The best direction of a solution is that you should use pull not push - that is install something on every computer and let them pull information.

The real problem with pushing information is that there are a lot of tools that stop this sort of think ( quite rightly ). Using tools like Net Send to share restaurant selections is network abuse, and if I was in charge of the network I would ban it.

Comment: well is there are some custom products where i can use  not develop or i can by and yes we have to set the application on each machine on the network thanks for your reply :)